# vscode на linux

Tags: ubuntu, visual-studio-code

Прошу помощи с vscode на ubuntu. Не работает вообще толком, ставил из магазина приложений снап пакет, жму на настройки в вскод и сразу выбирается последний пункт меню, такое ощущение что буд-то двойной клик происходит, так же не работает дублирование строки кода с помощю ALT + стрелка вверх/вниз.

Comment: [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)